# Сместить точку по перпендикуляру к отрезку

Tags: математика, геометрия

Никак не пойму, как сместить среднюю точку на отрезке по перпендикуляру к нему. Подскажите. Нахожу среднюю точку:

```
a.x + b.x / 2
a.y + b.y / 2
```

Нахожу коэффициент наклона перпендикулярной линии к отрезку:

```
-1 / ((b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x))
```

А далее нужно сместить точку по этой линии на определенное расстояние, допустим, `N`. Что делать?

Comment: В каком направлении? "По перпендикуляру" есть два направления.

Comment: @AnT, по идее, в случайном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коэффициентами наклона в выч. геометрии пользоваться не стоит.

```
//средняя точка
mx = (a.x + b.x) / 2
my = (a.y + b.y) / 2
//я добавил скобки
```

вектор разности

```
dx = b.x - a.x
dy = b.y - a.y
```

перпендикулярный вектор

```
nx = - dy
ny = dx
```

нормализованный (единичной длины) перпендикуляр

```
len = sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny)
unx = nx / len
uny = ny / len
```

Точка на срединном перпендикуляре на расстоянии D (разные знаки соответствуют двум точкам по обе стороны от отрезка)

```
px = mx +/- unx * D
py = my +/- uny * D
```

Comment: `uny = nx / len` - не `ny / len'?

Comment: Да, конечно.....